# Linq check unique value from a column with comma

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table where i am saving name in the pattern Firstname , Lastname

But while the user inputs this value the space between names might not be regular 
So how can i check the column value is unique using Linq

```
 string name_input = "a , b"; 
if (context.TableRankHolders.Any(q => q.Name == name_input))
{
  //name exists
}
```

What i am trying to do is format input string  to a strict pattern of "a , b" by removing all unwanted spaces before and after comma like in example

In database the Name values are in different formats like might be  no space between commas or more space between commas like "a,b" / "a ,b" / "a, b" / "a , b" etc
Now check using LINQ query , but how can i format name to split based on comma from the column

Only thing common is there must be  , present and i guess approach is like 
split by , and check part 0 and part 1 exists or not in db for a single row

Comment: what would be the value in `formatted_name`

Comment: Please see edit in description

Comment: I don't know your context, but it doesn't seem very usual to have first name + last name as a unique field. Two people may be easily named the same. That said, I'd personally remove all the white spaces and compare there're some chars, a comma and then some more chars. You never know what the user will input.

Comment: @msanz Yes u are right the intension to do this validation is to prevent entering the details of same persons again by mistake . If in case same name exits the client will make some adjustments in name like Jr or Sr etc to make it unique .

Comment: @msanz Separate fields will only [cause more problems](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). I would stop requesting `<firstname>, <lastname>` altogether and just let them enter their name as they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names do not have spaces in them you could go with simple:

```
context.TableRankHolders.Any(q => q.Name.Replace(" ", "") == name_input.Replace(" ", ""))
```

possibly checking for `null`s along the way. If you expect names to have spaces you should go with something along the lines of:

```
bool CheckNames(string a, string b)
{
    string[] splitA = a.Split(',').Select(q => q.Trim(' ')).ToArray();
    string[] splitB = b.Split(',').Select(q => q.Trim(' ')).ToArray();
    return splitA.SequenceEqual(splitB);
}

...
context.TableRankHolders.Any(q => CheckNames(q.Name, name_input))
```

Comment: Anyway to make String Format as a part of  LINQ where clause. If we can do so i can make something similar string.format("{0},{1}",name.split(,)[0],name.split(,)[1])

Comment: you could as well do that (keep in mind that the key part here is the `Trim` call) or just inline this function in the `Any` call (but this is not as readable IMO): `context.TableRankHolders.Any(q => q.Split(',').Select(w => w.Trim(' ')).SequenceEqual(name_input.Split(',').Select(w => w.Trim(' '))))`